# Que version de MariaDB necesito para que me funcione JSON_EXTRACT con el operador corto ->

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Hola buenas estoy ejecutando esta query de MySQL y me da error cuando intento hacer un extract del JSON que tengo. Y queria preguntar que version necesito de MariaDB para que funcione. Gracias

```
select * from order_discounts inner join orders on orders.id = order_discounts.order where order_discounts.discount_voucher_data->'$."id"' = 1 and orders.status > 0
```

```
Error cerca de >'$."id"'
```

Mi version actual de MariaDB es 10.1.x

Comment: Según los [comentarios en la documentación](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json_extract/) aún no esta disponible el operador `->`. [Acá la lista de operadores implementados](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operators/) hasta el momento

Comment: Muchas gracias @Marcos

Comment: Si te interesa saber como "avanza" la solución, [acá te dejo el enlace al issue en el Jira de MariaDB](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13594)